# Strip prefix /en/

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, .htaccess

Is there a way i can remove `/en/` from links I insert into a page for translated page?

This is what I do for the images:

```
RewriteRule ^en/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\.jpg wp-content/uploads/$1.jpg
```

That's what I do for `jpg`s loaded into one language and looked in another lang page.

What about links using the same kind of thing, maybe using jquery or php to replace any links in the html that gets outputted with /en/ ?

Comment: Okay, you've got three different approaches tagged in your question ([tag:htaccess], [tag:php] and [tag:javascript]), one is, effectively, 'server,' the next is 'server-side' and the last is 'client-side.' Which one do you actually want to use?

Comment: Please remove the Wordpress tag. It may be wp related, but is it wp only? No.

Comment: it is wp related. There maybe a js or php solution that could be used, maybe stripping the html? I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

It this what you wanted?

```
RewriteRule ^(..)/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\.jpg wp-content/uploads/$2.jpg
RewriteRule ^(..)/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\.jpeg wp-content/uploads/$2.jpeg
```

The `(..)` matches a two character sequence whereas `(.*)` has no length limit

Comment: isn't an upload is just a text link in this case. it's a page with content with a link which is translated and when it does the htrml gets the /en/ prefix